# Deploy Maven project to local Artifactory service

Tags: maven, ivy, artifactory, webjars

I have [forked](https://github.com/OpenCST/smart-table-webjar) a webjar project for working locally in my company's environment. We use Artifactory/Ivy for dependency management.

Currently Smart Table (and other webjars) `pom.xml` show the following for deployment:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.sonatype.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>nexus-staging-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.5</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <serverId>sonatype-nexus-staging</serverId>
                <nexusUrl>https://oss.sonatype.org/</nexusUrl>
                <autoReleaseAfterClose>true</autoReleaseAfterClose>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

It will by default publish to Sonatype, which is good for publicly-visible open source projects **once you have release credentials**.

However we do currently want to work locally on a fork of the project and deploy to **our local** Artifactory server. Contributions (to the real project) will be shared via Pull Request, so we are not interested in going to Sonatype repository.

### Question

How do I change Maven pom.xml so that `mvn deploy` will deploy to a locally-configured Artifactory service? (For which credentials are stored in Maven configuration of course)

### Bonus question

Can I tell Maven to publish using Ivy layout **or** should I create a new Maven-layout repository in Artifactory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First option is to use the standard [Maven deploy plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/usage.html)

```xml
<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
      <id>repo-id</id>
      <name>Artifactory</name>
      <url>http://server:8081/artifactory/repo-id</url>
    </repository>
  </distributionManagement>
```

You should configure your settings.xml file to define corresponding  entries which provides authentication information. Server entries are matched to the different parts of the distributionManagement using their  elements.

```xml
<server>
   <id>repo-id</id>
   <username>repo-username</username>
   <password>password/encrypted password</password>
</server>
```

Second option is to use the JFrog [Maven Artifactory plugin](http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Maven+Artifactory+Plugin), available at the [JCenter](http://jcenter.bintray.com/) repository in [Bintray](https://bintray.com)

```xml
<build>
    <plugins>
        ...
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jfrog.buildinfo</groupId>
            <artifactId>artifactory-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
            <inherited>false</inherited>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>build-info</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>publish</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <deployProperties>
                            <gradle>awesome</gradle>
                            <review.team>qa</review.team>
                        </deployProperties>
                        <publisher>
                            <contextUrl>https://server:8081/artifactory</contextUrl>
                            <username>username</username>
                            <password>{DESede}...</password>
                            <repoKey>libs-release-local</repoKey>
                            <snapshotRepoKey>libs-snapshot-local</snapshotRepoKey>
                        </publisher>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Through the Maven Artifactory Plugin, Artifactory is fully integrated with Maven builds and allows you to do the following:

1. Attach properties to published artifacts in Artifactory metadata.
2. Capture a BuildInfo object which can be passed to the Artifactory REST API to provide a fully traceable build context.
3. Automatically publish all build artifacts at the end of the build.

More detailed usage examples of the plugin can be found in this [Github project](https://github.com/JFrogDev/project-examples/tree/master/artifactory-maven-plugin-example).

**Bonus question**

Maven can only deploy to a Maven2 (default) or Maven1 (legacy) layout repository. You will have to create a new Maven repository in Artifactory.